# React Navigation Shared Element Transitions not animating when screen is replaced in stack or navigate to another stack

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-reanimated

Tried shared element transition of react native reanimated which is working perfectly fine when screen is navigated to another screen within the same stack but if screen is replaced with the screen present in same stack the transition never take places also even if screen navigated with the screen from different stack in that case also the transition never takes place.

I tried placing all the screens in same stack and navigating to the screens such that for the scenario where replacing in the stack was needed i reset navigation history but even in that case the transition is buggy.